# Closest int that a Double is to in Java

Tags: java

I have a bunch of int values like 10, 5, 4, 2, 1. And I have a bunch of `Double` values in a `List<Double>` like 0.65 etc etc.

How can I go through this list a check which int value each Double is closest to?

My code was for an android music app. Here is how I ended up solving it.

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String[] noteNames = new String[9];
                double[] notes = new double[9];
                double crotchet = 60.0 / Long.parseLong(setBPM.getText().toString());
                double quaver = crotchet / 2.0;
                double tripletQuaver = crotchet / 3.0;
                double dottedCrotchet = crotchet + quaver;
                double semiquaver = quaver / 2.0; 
                double dottedQuaver = quaver + semiquaver;
                double minum = crotchet * 2.0;
                double dottedMinum = minum + crotchet;
                double semibreve = minum * 2.0;
                notes[0] = semiquaver;
                notes[1] = tripletQuaver;
                notes[2] = quaver;
                notes[3] = dottedQuaver;
                notes[4] = crotchet;
                notes[5] = dottedCrotchet;
                notes[6] = minum;
                notes[7] = dottedMinum;
                notes[8] = semibreve;
                noteNames[0] = "semiquaver";
                noteNames[1] = "tripletQuaver";
                noteNames[2] = "quaver";
                noteNames[3] = "dottedQuaver";
                noteNames[4] = "crotchet";
                noteNames[5] = "dottedCrotchet";
                noteNames[6] = "minum";
                noteNames[7] = "dottedMinum";
                noteNames[8] = "semibreve";
                for(double l : notes) {
                    System.out.println(l);
                }
                double[] tempCurrentDiff = new double[9];
                double[] currentDiff = new double[9];
                for (Double d : beats) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                        currentDiff[i] = Math.abs(notes[i] - d);
                        tempCurrentDiff[i] = Math.abs(notes[i] - d);
                    }
                    Arrays.sort(tempCurrentDiff);
                    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
                        if (currentDiff[i] == tempCurrentDiff[0]) {
                            System.out.println(noteNames[i]);
                            notesView.append(noteNames[i] + " ");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
          }
```

Comment: I don't get it - you're looking for `Math.round()`? Can you clarify?

Comment: And can you cut out the code that is irrelevant to the question?

Comment: @Teepeemm I think it's fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**`Math.round(double)`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29) function to round your each element of your list. `Math.round(double)` Returns the *closest* `long` to the argument, with ties(`0.5`) rounding up. However, If the argument is `NaN`, the result is `0`.

**So**,

1. sort your given integer array `int[] a` using `Arrays.sort(a)`, if not already sorted
2. go through the list for each double `x`
3. find integer `key = Math.round(x)`
4. use [**`Arrays.binarySearch(a, key)`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29); where `a` is an `int[]` containing your integer array elements. This function might return a `negative index` if the element is not present in the array `a`. The `negative index: (-(insertion point) - 1).` representing the insertion point of the array we are searching in.

**sample code:**

```
double doub[] = {0.5, 2.6, 3.7, 1.7, 4.6};
  long a[] = {1, 4, 3}; //

  Arrays.sort(a);
  for(double x : doub)
  {
      long key = Math.round(x);
      int index = Arrays.binarySearch(a, key);
      if(index < 0) // element wasn't found
           index = - index -1;
      if(index > a.length -1) // key is greater than the maximum element 
         index = a.length - 1;

      System.out.println("double: "+x+" rounded key: "+key+" value: "+a[index]);

  }
```

Comment: And how should I go about checking which int its closest to

Comment: It will give you closest `long` integer

Comment: Even though a binary search would perform better, I think a brute-force approach might be more appropriate for a new programmer, rather than having to sort the data then work out the logic of determining if the exact result was found and, if not, which side of the insertion point is closer.

Comment: @Sage most of the time binarySearch will return a negative number.  Need to check for that and correct.

Comment: @user949300, thanks for your mentioning. I was writing that at the time of your comment though :)

Comment: @Clay, i have updated the answer. You were getting the `null` pointer because of the index and non presence of the `key` inside the integer `array a`. please check the linked DOC of `binarySeach` for details. However with current update you should not have any problem

Comment: @sage its a nice piece of code but its still not working how i want. for exmaple Im geting 0.53, its closest to 0.5 but its rounding to 1 and saying its closer to 1

Comment: @Clay, yes any value `x` if `0.5 <= x <= 1` it is closer to `1`. otherwise `x` is closer to `0`

Comment: @Clay, your question is put on as hold. Please edit your question demonstrating your attempt for solving it. :)

Answer (score 2):

First, use `Math.round()` as the others suggest to get an int.  Then, if your ints are order, look at `Arrays.binarySearch().`

Comment: Yes, binarySearch() will often return a negative value which he can use to figure out which is closest.  Give it a look, then please reconsider your downvote.  :-). I see you did - thank you.

Comment: Even though a binary search would perform better, I think a brute-force approach might be more appropriate for a new programmer, rather than having to sort the data then work out the logic of determining if the exact result was found and, if not, which side of the insertion point is closer.

Comment: @Jason. Point noted, you may be right.  Working out the math for the negative "find" is a pain and tricky.  I'm not giving him the logic to force OP to try to work it out.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to *try* something then post here when you have a problem.

However, as a hint: For each of your doubles, go through your integer list. For each integer, compute the distance of your double to that integer. If the computed distance is smaller than the current minimum, that's the new minimum.

It really helps to work these kinds of things out on paper first. How would a *human* do it? If you can work that out, then it will be much easier for you to translate it to a program.

Comment: +1 To add to this for OP, you have probably seen example code to find the minimum of an array of numbers.  In this case, you have one extra step to take a difference, but general scheme will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try to find smallest value of `listOfDoubles.get(i) - anyInteger`, then store smallest difference's index `i`

```
if (difference < min) {
    do something...
}
```

Just an idea of how I would do that.

Answer (score 0):

`Math.round(Double d)` in `java.lang.Math` will take a `Double` object and round it to the nearest `Long` with ties (`.5`) rounding up.

See: [Oracle Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29)